# Adding an attribute to customer order page on the backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I want to add a custom attribute which i have already created to the order page in the back end. I have used this in my config.xml file to add the attribute to the customer account page, but I want to access the same field from the Order page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shailendra_CustomField>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Shailendra_CustomField>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customfield>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Shailendra_CustomField</module>
                    <frontName>customfield</frontName>
                </args>
            </customfield>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customfield>
                    <file>customfield.xml</file>
                </customfield>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <customfield>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Shailendra_CustomField</module>
                    <frontName>customfield</frontName>
                </args>
            </customfield>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
     <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
            <occupation>
                <to_quote>occupation</to_quote>
            </occupation>
        </customer_account>       
      </fieldsets>
    </global>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                 <occupation><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></occupation>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customfield_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Shailendra_CustomField</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customfield_setup>
            <customfield_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customfield_write>
            <customfield_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customfield_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Would i have to just add something to this config file. If so what would i have to add.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to add `my_custom_input_field` to your order and add a field to your admin create order page (to add the field to the frontend you just need to add the input field to the front template and double check the observer)

In `/app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderStatus/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus>
    </modules>

    <global> 
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <my_custom_input_field><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <my_custom_input_field><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <customorderstatus>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Helper</class>
            </customorderstatus>            
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <customorderstatus>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customorderstatus_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </customorderstatus>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customorderstatus_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customorderstatus_setup>
            <customorderstatus_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customorderstatus_write>
            <customorderstatus_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customorderstatus_read>
        </resources>

        <events>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
                <observers>
                    <customorderstatus>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customorderstatus/observer</class>
                        <method>saveCustomData</method>
                    </customorderstatus>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <customorderstatus>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Block</class>
            </customorderstatus>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

In `/app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderStatus/sql/customorderstatus_setup/mysql4-install-1.1.php`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

In `/app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderStatus/Model/Observer.php`

```
class MageIgniter_CustomOrderStatus_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomData($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getSession()->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field', $event->getRequestModel()->getPost('my_custom_input_field'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

(You should avoid make changes to core default - you should do some research on way around this)

In `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml`

```
<?php if($_order->getMyCustomInputField()): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Custom Input Field') ?></label></td>
    <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getMyCustomInputField() ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form/account.phtml`

(to add to frontend change the `value="<?php echo Mage...>"`)

```
<input id="my_custom_input_field" name="my_custom_input_field" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote()->getMyCustomInputField() ?>" class="input-text" type="text">
```

Comment: But i have already created the field as it is in my customer account page. I just want to get drag the information that is stored in the account into the order

Comment: you can get help from this code. look below of this line : "(You should avoid make changes to core default - you should do some research on way around this)"

Comment: Thank you i ahve tried to modify it to suite my needs and came up with this : <?php $acc = $this->getCustomerAccountData(accref);?> As my field in the Account data is called accref then i can juest echo $acc. but it doesnt work.

Comment: Change from <?php $acc = $this->getCustomerAccountData(accref);?>  to <?php $acc = $this->getCustomerAccountData('accref');?> and see what happen

Comment: When i echo $acc it returns "Array". When i var_dump it is says "array(0) { }".

Comment: Could it be because the data for accref is not being in putted during the order?

Comment: Yes because it's returning empty array.you can test my module if it's work for you then you can use same

Comment: I don't understand why it is returning an empty array though when the field accreff is filled in on the account page? and is stored in the database